# Displaying random XML file in DataGrid

Tags: c#, xml

I have been following [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307548) article to read an XML file into a datagridview control.

I am posting the relevant piece of code here.

```
string filePath = "Complete path where you saved the XML file";
dsAuthors.ReadXml(filePath);
dataGrid1.DataSource = dsAuthors;
dataGrid1.DataMember = "authors";
dataGrid1.CaptionText = dataGrid1.DataMember;
```

**Now I want to be able to read any XML file** without knowing the elements of the XML file, but the above method requires me to declare the `dataGrid1.DataMember = "authors";` which in case of random XML file, I will not know.

Thanks,

Abijeet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a little luck the following property has been filled:

```
dataGrid1.DataMember = dsAuthors.Tables[0].Tablename;
```

Comment: This worked! But why the need for luck? Also is there a better way to read a random XML file into a datagrid?

Comment: It depends on how the XML was created. I think the DS is able to read xml w/o tablenames.